# Quality must range from 0 to 100 - Intervention Laravel 5.x

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, intervention

I'm using `intervention/image 2.3`. When I try to upload an image I got the following error :

> InvalidArgumentException in AbstractEncoder.php line 212
>
> Quality must range from 0 to 100

Below is my code for that :

```
$file = Input::file('image');
$filename = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
Image::make($file)->resize(50, 50)->save(storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads', $filename);
```

Any single guidance will help me alot.
According to [this](http://image.intervention.io/api/save) URL I tried out to pass second optional parameter ie quality but didn't work. I tried even

```
Image::make($file)->resize(50, 50)->save(storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads'. $filename, 50);
```

Comment: Oh! I got the error. There was comma in my code. `Image::make($file)->resize(50, 50)->save(storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads', $filename);` before `$filename`. It should be `.`

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem, and I solved it by the following code:

```
$file = $request->file('img_profile');
$file_name = date('Ymd-his').'.png';
$destinationPath = 'uploads/images/';
$new_img = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(400, 300);

// save file with medium quality
$new_img->save($destinationPath . $file_name, 80);
```

Check http://image.intervention.io/api/save for more...

Answer (score 0):

`save()` method's 1st argument should be path+name, 2nd quality (0-100), you used "`,`" between path and `$filename` instead of `.` 
Do something like 
`->save('your/path/'.$filename);` or `->save('your/path/'.$filename, 80);`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem, use the save() like this

```
$image = $request->file('img_src');
$filename = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
$image_resize->fit(250);
$image_resize->save(public_path('/imgs/'.$filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing *file name* in place of *quality* parameter.

Possibly you are rewriting basic from $file->move() method?
Just replace comma with one more DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR:

```
Image::make($file)->resize(50, 50)->save(storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
```